# hiding a link in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

In the following master.cs code:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BasePage page = (BasePage)Page;

        if (page.CurrentUser != null)
        {
            lblCurrentUser.Text = "<strong>" + page.CurrentUser.FullName + "</strong> - " + page.CurrentUser.CompanyName;

            if ((Session["CCFUser"] != null) && (bool.Parse(Session["CCFUser"].ToString()) == true))
            {
                ctrlLinkBar.AddLink("Issues Management", "AllIssues.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                if (true) ctrlLinkBar.AddLink("Home", "Default.aspx");
                if (page.CurrentUser.Permissions.Issues()) ctrlLinkBar.AddLink("Issues Management", "AllIssues.aspx");
                if (page.CurrentUser.Permissions.Time()) ctrlLinkBar.AddLink("Time Management", "TimeEntryForm.aspx");
                if (page.CurrentUser.Permissions.Time()) ctrlLinkBar.AddLink("Time Filter", "TimeFilter.aspx");
                if (page.CurrentUser.Permissions.SVN() && !(this.Page is _Default)) ctrlLinkBar.AddLink("SVN", "SVN.aspx");
                if (true) ctrlLinkBar.AddLink("Profile", "ChangePassword.aspx");
                if (page.CurrentUser.Permissions.Administration()) ctrlLinkBar.AddLink("Administration", "Administration.aspx");
            }

        }
        else lnkLogout.Visible = false;
    }
    protected void lnkLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

i need to hide the link "Time Filter" so it doesnt appear on any of the web content forms.
It doesnt have an id so i cannot caste it. How do I go about hiding it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about editing Master.cs to not add it, or only add it some of the time?

If that doesn't work, then you need to give us more context.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make ctrlLinkBar.AddLink take an Id in its constructor and create the link with an Id?

```
ctrlLinkBar.AddLink("TimeFilterId", "Time Filter", "TimeFilter.aspx");
```

Then, your content pages or whatever can find it and hide when needed.

Comment: I tried that. 
But I am getting an erroe "no overload for method "AddLink" takes 3 arguments".

Comment: What is ctrlLinkBar?  I assumed it was something you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? Why not just delete the line?

```
if (page.CurrentUser.Permissions.Time()) 
  ctrlLinkBar.AddLink("Time Filter", "TimeFilter.aspx");
```